# Python dictionary of lists maximum based on on 3rd element from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, max

I have a dictionary of lists

```
 h={'1':['a','3','56'],'2':['a','2','125']}
```

I want to get the key and value for the maximum based on third element of `h[k]` i.e `(2,125)`

I tried to understand `lambda` function and wrote this:

```
 max(h, key=lambda h : int(h[k][2]) for k in h.keys())
```

But it  gives me a `SyntaxError` error.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please explain a bit more? Why are you considering only `2` and `125`?

Comment: @thefourtheye because 125 is greater than 56, and it's in the list with key "2"

Comment: I forgot to cast to int here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes. The nearest correction can be:-

```
>>> max(h, key=lambda k : h[k][2])
'1'
>>> h={'1':['a','3','56'],'2':['a','2','125']}
>>> max(h, key=lambda k : int(h[k][2]))
'2'
>>> maxval = max(h, key=lambda k : int(h[k][2]))
>>> h[maxval]
['a', '2', '125']
```

The mistakes can be listed as

- The key is evaluated for each entry, So you don't need to have a `for` loop
- The `lambda` function works as `lambda args: returnvalue` so your `lambda function semantically incorrect

Apart from that, you are comparing lexicographically, so `'125'` is lesser than `'56'` so you need to convert them to `int` type before checking them out.

To get your exact output you can do

```
>>> print("{},{}".format(int(maxval),h[maxval]))
2,['a', '2', '125']
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2.7 you could do the following:

```
max(h.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v):int(v[2]))
```

This will give you the corresponding key and value as a tuple.  This is also assuming you want to interpret those values as integers (and doesn't make any attempts to handle the cases where your data does not have a valid conversion to integers).  If you want to determine the "max" based on a lex sort, you can just remove the `int` cast in the lambda function.

If you are in Python 3, this is roughly equivalent:

```
max(h.items(), key=lambda kv:int(kv[1][2]))
```